# exec() function deactivated for security reasons

Tags: php, security

I use a plugin to compress the images on my website and this plugin needs to use  `jpegtran`, `optipng` and `gifsicle`. I asked my hosting service why these weren't enabled and they answered that they disable the `exec()` function for security reasons. Should I ask them to allow this function or is it to risky?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language.

Comment: Is this shared hosting or a VPS?

Comment: It's trafficplanet so it's managed hosting but I don't think it's shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and ask. They are correct however in that exec is a security risk. Check with your plugin, there may be a way for it to use the GD image library, which requires no exec functions to operate on images.